# How do QThreads work when being run twice?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyside, qthread

In another class:

```
self.workerThread = WorkerThread()

def startThread():
    self.workerThread.setGameName("pizza")
    self.workerThread.start()
```

QThread class:

```
class WorkerThread(QThread):
    def _init_(self, parent = None):
        super(WorkerThread, self)._init_(parent)
        self.gameName = ""

    def setGameName(self, currGameName):
        self.gameName = currGameName

    def run(self):
        #do something with self.gameName
```

In main:

```
startThread()
startThread()
```

When I run this, it uses the gameName from the first call and not the second. The function calls seem interleaved. Can someone explain how Qthread works? How do i set a gameName for each individual function call of startThread()?

Answer (score 1):

If `start()` is called twice on a `QThread` then the second call will do nothing if the thread is still running. It looks like there's a good chance this is what's happening, and if not then it's only due to luck.